# PEAR - No releases available for package

Tags: pear

When I try to download a package through pear it gives me this error (it's not just for phpunit):

```
No releases available for package "pear.phpunit.de/phpunit"
install failed
```

I tried with `sudo pear clear-cache` and it says:

```
/tmp/pear/cache does not exist or is not a directory
```

I also tried with `sudo pear update-channels` and everything is up to date:

```
Updating channel "components.ez.no"
Channel "components.ez.no" is up to date
Updating channel "doc.php.net"
Channel "doc.php.net" is up to date
Updating channel "guzzlephp.org/pear"
Channel "guzzlephp.org/pear" is up to date
Updating channel "nikic.github.com/pear"
Channel "nikic.github.com/pear" is up to date
Updating channel "pear.amazonwebservices.com"
Channel "pear.amazonwebservices.com" is up to date
Updating channel "pear.andrewsville.cz"
Channel "pear.andrewsville.cz" is up to date
Updating channel "pear.apache.org/log4php"
Channel "pear.apache.org/log4php" is up to date
Updating channel "pear.apache.org/oodt"
Channel "pear.apache.org/oodt" is up to date
Updating channel "pear.apache.org/zetacomponents"
Channel "pear.apache.org/zetacomponents" is up to date
Updating channel "pear.apigen.org"
Channel "pear.apigen.org" is not responding over http://, failed with message: File http://pear.apigen.org:80/channel.xml not valid (received: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
)
Trying channel "pear.apigen.org" over https:// instead
Cannot retrieve channel.xml for channel "pear.apigen.org" (File https://pear.apigen.org:443/channel.xml not valid (received: HTTP/1.1 500 Domain Not Found
))
Updating channel "pear.doctrine-project.org"
Channel "pear.doctrine-project.org" is up to date
Updating channel "pear.dropbox-php.com"
Channel "pear.dropbox-php.com" is up to date
Updating channel "pear.horde.org"
Channel "pear.horde.org" is up to date
Updating channel "pear.kukulich.cz"
Channel "pear.kukulich.cz" is up to date
Updating channel "pear.michelf.com"
Channel "pear.michelf.com" is up to date
Updating channel "pear.netpirates.net"
Channel "pear.netpirates.net" is up to date
Updating channel "pear.nette.org"
Channel "pear.nette.org" is up to date
Updating channel "pear.pdepend.org"
Channel "pear.pdepend.org" is up to date
Updating channel "pear.phing.info"
Channel "pear.phing.info" is up to date
Updating channel "pear.php.net"
Channel "pear.php.net" is up to date
Updating channel "pear.phpdoc.org"
Channel "pear.phpdoc.org" is up to date
Updating channel "pear.phpmd.org"
Channel "pear.phpmd.org" is up to date
Updating channel "pear.phpunit.de"
Channel "pear.phpunit.de" is not responding over http://, failed with message: File http://pear.phpunit.de:80/channel.xml not valid (received: HTTP/1.1 410 Gone
)
Trying channel "pear.phpunit.de" over https:// instead
Cannot retrieve channel.xml for channel "pear.phpunit.de" (File https://pear.phpunit.de:443/channel.xml not valid (received: HTTP/1.1 410 Gone
))
Updating channel "pear.propelorm.org"
Channel "pear.propelorm.org" is up to date
Updating channel "pear.symfony-project.com"
Channel "pear.symfony-project.com" is up to date
Updating channel "pear.symfony.com"
Channel "pear.symfony.com" is up to date
Updating channel "pear.texy.info"
Channel "pear.texy.info" is up to date
Updating channel "pear.twig-project.org"
Channel "pear.twig-project.org" is up to date
Updating channel "pecl.php.net"
Channel "pecl.php.net" is up to date
milen@milen-Inspiron-N5010:/opt/lampp/php$ sudo pear install --alldeps --force phpunit/phpunit
No releases available for package "pear.phpunit.de/phpunit"
install failed
milen@milen-Inspiron-N5010:/opt/lampp/php$ pear install PHP_CodeSniffer
No releases available for package "pear.php.net/PHP_CodeSniffer"
install failed
milen@milen-Inspiron-N5010:/opt/lampp/php$ sudo pear clear-cache
/tmp/pear/cache does not exist or is not a directory
milen@milen-Inspiron-N5010:/opt/lampp/php$ sudo pear clear-cache/tmp/pear/cache does not exist or is not a directory
milen@milen-Inspiron-N5010:/opt/lampp/php$ sudo pear update-channelsUpdating channel "components.ez.no"
Channel "components.ez.no" is up to date
Updating channel "doc.php.net"
Channel "doc.php.net" is up to date
Updating channel "guzzlephp.org/pear"
Channel "guzzlephp.org/pear" is up to date
Updating channel "nikic.github.com/pear"
Channel "nikic.github.com/pear" is up to date
Updating channel "pear.amazonwebservices.com"
Channel "pear.amazonwebservices.com" is up to date
Updating channel "pear.andrewsville.cz"
Channel "pear.andrewsville.cz" is up to date
Updating channel "pear.apache.org/log4php"
Channel "pear.apache.org/log4php" is up to date
Updating channel "pear.apache.org/oodt"
Channel "pear.apache.org/oodt" is up to date
Updating channel "pear.apache.org/zetacomponents"
Channel "pear.apache.org/zetacomponents" is up to date
Updating channel "pear.apigen.org"
Channel "pear.apigen.org" is not responding over http://, failed with message: File http://pear.apigen.org:80/channel.xml not valid (received: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
)
Trying channel "pear.apigen.org" over https:// instead
Cannot retrieve channel.xml for channel "pear.apigen.org" (File https://pear.apigen.org:443/channel.xml not valid (received: HTTP/1.1 500 Domain Not Found
))
Updating channel "pear.doctrine-project.org"
Channel "pear.doctrine-project.org" is up to date
Updating channel "pear.dropbox-php.com"
Channel "pear.dropbox-php.com" is up to date
Updating channel "pear.horde.org"
Channel "pear.horde.org" is up to date
Updating channel "pear.kukulich.cz"
Channel "pear.kukulich.cz" is up to date
Updating channel "pear.michelf.com"
Channel "pear.michelf.com" is up to date
Updating channel "pear.netpirates.net"
Channel "pear.netpirates.net" is up to date
Updating channel "pear.nette.org"
Channel "pear.nette.org" is up to date
Updating channel "pear.pdepend.org"
Channel "pear.pdepend.org" is up to date
Updating channel "pear.phing.info"
Channel "pear.phing.info" is up to date
Updating channel "pear.php.net"
Channel "pear.php.net" is up to date
Updating channel "pear.phpdoc.org"
Channel "pear.phpdoc.org" is up to date
Updating channel "pear.phpmd.org"
Channel "pear.phpmd.org" is up to date
Updating channel "pear.phpunit.de"
Channel "pear.phpunit.de" is not responding over http://, failed with message: File http://pear.phpunit.de:80/channel.xml not valid (received: HTTP/1.1 410 Gone
)
Trying channel "pear.phpunit.de" over https:// instead
Cannot retrieve channel.xml for channel "pear.phpunit.de" (File https://pear.phpunit.de:443/channel.xml not valid (received: HTTP/1.1 410 Gone
))
Updating channel "pear.propelorm.org"
Channel "pear.propelorm.org" is up to date
Updating channel "pear.symfony-project.com"
Channel "pear.symfony-project.com" is up to date
Updating channel "pear.symfony.com"
Channel "pear.symfony.com" is up to date
Updating channel "pear.texy.info"
Channel "pear.texy.info" is up to date
Updating channel "pear.twig-project.org"
Channel "pear.twig-project.org" is up to date
Updating channel "pecl.php.net"
Channel "pecl.php.net" is up to date
```

It still can't download anything, what's up with that ?

Answer (score 1):

phpunit isn't available via pear anymore (not since December 2014). You can download it as a .phar or install it via composer instead.

[More details are available on the phpunit.de website.](https://phpunit.de/getting-started.html)

Comment: Like I said, I can't download anything through pear, not only phpunit

Comment: What errors do you specifically get when attempting to install a pear package? e.g. $sudo pear install pear/Net_FTP

Comment: No releases available for package